# Trying to make a box of a specific size based around a link - not working

Tags: css

Trying to add a box around a menu of links in Wordpress. So far I've got this - which should make a box of 150px x 50px if I am correct. However, while margin, padding, etc, all work, this does not. Why would that be the case? Has width become deprecated in recent CSS?

```
.menu-header .menu-item {
    display: inline !important;
    margin: 0px 50px !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 2px !important;
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    background-color: #EDEDED !important;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: inline` - that will cause problems with setting a size.  The element needs to be block level to specify the size.

Also, the CSS can be simplified:

```
.menu-header .menu-item{
    margin: 0 50px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #EDEDED;
}​
```

Comment: Your "simplified" CSS is subtly different from his original CSS (and I'm not referring to the `!important` change, either.)

Comment: I did add the #000 color to the border.

Answer (score 0):

display:inline and width 150px collide with each other.
An inline element has at every time the width of it's content.

You could set the display to inline-block when you really need it inline or else to block.

Comment: How would I make the list horizontal then?

Comment: Yea, the size is great, but it's no longer horizontal.